# Start different Neo4j versions in the same program

Tags: java, neo4j

Is it possible to start different Neo4j versions in the same java program?

I'd like to start different Versions of Neo4j in different Threads.
(Multiversion programming - Fault tolerance purposes)
I don't need them to interact in HA mode, they will interact through my own interface.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can connect to different Neo4j servers and make cypher requests to those.

I wouldn't recommend writing an unmanaged server extension that connects to different environments though.

Comment: Yeah but can I start them also from java like this:
        graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(dbPath).newGraphDatabase();

It's a university project. It's for experiment not for productive use.